# When to use a non-generic interface as a generic type constraint

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I am struggling to find a scenario where it would make sense to use a non-generic interface as a generic type constraint. Below is an arbitrary example where the non-generic method (RideCar2) is simpler than the generic method RideCar.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var car = new Merc();
        RideCar(car);
        RideCar2(car);
    }

    static void RideCar<T>(T t) where T : ICar
    {
        t.StartEngine();
        t.StopEngine();
    }

    static void RideCar2(ICar car)
    {
        car.StartEngine();
        car.StopEngine();
    }
}

public interface ICar
{
    void StartEngine();
    void StopEngine();
}

public class Merc : ICar
{
    public void StartEngine() { Console.WriteLine("Merc start"); }
    public void StopEngine() { Console.WriteLine("Merc stop"); }
}
```

It is obvious that RideCar2 is a much better implementation as it has less noise.

**Is there a scenario where a non-generic interface used as a generic type constraint makes sense?**

**FURTHER EXAMPLES (As per the responses)**

1. Using as return type

```
static T RideCar(T t) where T : ICar
{
    t.StartEngine();
    t.StopEngine();
    return t;
}
```

Using a normal method still renders use of generic method useless, see below:

```
static ICar RideCar(ICar car)
{
 car.StartEngine();
 car.StopEngine();
 return car;
}
```

2. Multiple interfaces

```
static void RideCar(T t) where T : ICar, ICanTimeTravel
{
    t.StartEngine();      // ICar
    t.TravelToYear(1955); // ICanTimeTravel
    t.StopEngine();       // ICar
}
```

Using a normal method with multiple paramaters still renders use of generic method useless, see below:

```
static void RideCar(ICar car, ICanTimeTravel canTimeTravel)
{
 car.StartEngine();
 canTimeTravel.TravelToYear(1955);
 car.StopEngine();
}
```

Comment: When you need multiple interface constraints

Comment: Look at an example where the generic method *returns* a value of the generic type.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever For me that would be the best answer

Comment: The problem with your example `static void RideCar(ICar car, ICanTimeTravel canTimeTravel)` is that there is nothing to be gained by doing it this way instead of using generic constraints.  It makes the code less clear because there is no constraint telling the caller that the car and the time machine are the same device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is. Consider:

```
static T RideCar<T>(T t) where T : ICar
{
    t.StartEngine();
    t.StopEngine();
    return t;
}
```

This will return the specific type. Now you can use the implementation specifics without having to cast it back to the implementation type, which is bad practice.

Also, you can have **multiple** interface constraints on the same generic argument:

```
static void RideCar<T>(T t) where T : ICar, ICanTimeTravel
{
    t.StartEngine();      // ICar
    t.TravelToYear(1955); // ICanTimeTravel
    t.StopEngine();       // ICar
}
```

Lastly, even though this is *sometimes* considered code smell, you can use the `new()` constraint along with your interface constraint, in order to create instances of your implementation type inside the method:

```
static T Create<T>() where T : ICar, new()
{
    T t = new T();
    return t;
}
```

Comment: The first 2 examples still do not require a generic method (see my updates to the original post). In the 3rd example the non-generic interface (ICar) is used to constrain the creation of the type which is useful.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. In your case the non-generic way is preferred.

If you want to call methods that are declared on different interfaces then the generic-declaration with type-constraints makes sense:

```
public void Test<T>(T value, T other) 
    where T: IEquatable<T>, IComparable<T>
{
    value.Equals(other); //in IEquatable<T>
    value.CompareTo(other); //in IComparable<T>
}
```

But in that case I prefer using a base class if possible and use it in the following method without any type-constraints:

```
public class BaseCar<T> : IEquatable<T>, IComparable<T>, ICar
{
    /// [...]
}

public void Test<T>(BaseCar<T> car1, BaseCar<T> car2)
    where T: IEquatable<T>, IComparable<T>
{
    car1.Equals(car2);
    car1.CompareTo(car2);
}
```

or without generics but limitation to ICar:

```
public class BaseCar : IEquatable<ICar>, IComparable<ICar>
{
    /// [...]
}

public void Test(BaseCar car1, BaseCar car2)
{
    car1.Equals(car2);
    car2.CompareTo(car2);
}
```

Comment: IEquatable<>,IComparable<> are generic interfaces. I asked when it would be useful to use non-generic interfaces as type constraints for generic methods.